# Maintaining chainability in jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I recently started fooling around with jQuery plugins and began write mine a couple of hours ago. Concepts are still very new to me and have a hard time putting it all together so feel free to criticize.

I'm working on a dummy plugin where there the users get an alert about a session expiration. Once the session "expires", a method fires (custom or default) based on the given parameters:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.sessionTimeout = function(options) {

    var plugin = this;
    var lgouttime;
    var defaults = {
        refresh: 1000,
        totalTime : 2, // in seconds
        showCountDown: 'countdown',
        timeout: null
    }

    plugin.init = function() {
        plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        // start countdown 
        plugin.timer();


    }   
    /* settings */      
    plugin.settings = {}
    /* timer */
    plugin.timer = function() {
        lgouttime = setInterval(function(){
            plugin.settings.totalTime = plugin.settings.totalTime-1;    
            if(plugin.settings.showCountDown != null) {
                $('#'+plugin.settings.showCountDown).html(plugin.settings.totalTime);
            }

            if(plugin.settings.totalTime==0) {
                clearInterval(lgouttime);
                if( $.isFunction(plugin.settings.timeout) ) {
                    console.log(plugin.settings.totalTime);
                    plugin.settings.timeout.call(plugin);   
                }
            }

        }, plugin.settings.refresh);
    }

    plugin.init();
    return this;

};

})(jQuery);
```

And this would be used as:

```
$('body').sessionTimeout({ 

    timeout: function() {
                /* do some other stuff here */
            $(this).divDiag({ // however,  'this' does not carry forward for some reason in any other plugin
                "icon" : "trash",
                "genmsg_id" : "gen_msg",
                "mainID" : "sessionTimeout",
                "contents" : 'Session expired.' 
            });         


    }
});
```

Now everything works fine, but cannot get 'this' to carry forward in any subsequent plugins. Any ideas on how to do this.

Comment: What is divDiag? Your value of 'this' is working, but your plugin isn't being loaded right.

Comment: @ncksllvn divDiag is another plugin I found. Perhaps it's the fault of that plugin?

Comment: I ran your code in a fiddle, and it was crashing on divDiag as undefined. I'd say that's your problem. If it's in fact being loaded right, make sure you're using the right version of jQuery for it.

Comment: @ncksllvn hmm, I'll have to check that out...

Comment: An easy way to test is to take that function out of the timeout function and see if it works on its own. I would be surprised if it did.

Comment: How do you expect to chain it? `$('body').sessionTimeout().addClass('timed-out')`

Comment: Not sure what else is going on, but your plugin works as expected. Created a full app to test it in VS 2013's debugger and it is passing `body` as this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Okay. Ignore my other answer (deleted) as your specific add-in only appears to need to attach one instance only (to body). This kind of makes using jQuery plugin code pointless, as you do not target anything specific to the attached element. It could just as easily been a static extension on the jQuery instance instead.*

I just build a test web-app *so I could bring the might of Visual Studio's debugger into play and found...*.

**...your sample works just fine:**

`$(this)` does indeed carry through to your `plugin.settings.timeout` call. The additional `divDiag` extension you are trying to access on it however does not exist in your sample code, but if I replace it with something simpler like this it works just fine:

```
$(function () {
    $('body').sessionTimeout({
        showCountDown: "countdown",
        timeout: function () {
            alert(this);
            /* do some other stuff here */
            $(this).append("<h1>I am body!</h1>")
        }
    }).css("background-color", "yellow");  // Chains here too
});
```

Result:

[image]

*Please recheck your code for problems elsewhere.*

Comment: Well it seems as though the second plugin is what's causing the problem because I see no other issue. Thanks very much for the help! :)